# Log into application with Windows Network Authentication

Tags: c#, windows, vb.net, authentication

Not sure if there is another thread with the answer, but tried looking and nothing stood out.

Our company runs Windows Server 2008 R2 and as part of the normal login procedure you type your username and password. IT sets the domain when you get your PC so that is all good. So, when you open IE, the intranet sight detects that you are person XXX YYY and then logs you into the site automatically as the right person.

Now is there any way that I can do the same with an application written in C# or VB.NET. I.e., I would like the user to not have to log in as they have already done so during Windows log in, and then use the application as the indicidual user. This is for loggin purposes and specific rights for each group. (like admins or guests etc)

Comment: given that you want a distinction between admin and guests then there must be some kind of shared component which your users are manipulating. what is this?

Comment: it will be information like their phone numbers and wanting to share only certain information with other users. I.e. like a phone directory, but not all users want to have their mobile no displayed. however, only admins and the actual logged in user should be able to change either the no. or setting

Comment: yes, but change it where? what is the shared component which holds this data? SQL Server? MSAccess? a web service? a file on a network share?

Comment: MSAccess would the storing all the information and it will be on a server drive. I.e. P:\Data\Phonelist

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Environment.UserName` to get the username of the current user, but you will still need to store some permissions pertaining to this user somewhere.

You can make people a member of an Active Directory group and then grant them permissions based on which group they are a member of but this will require that you (or your application) has the ability to create AD groups and move people in and out of them. If you need some pointers to this then I can find some code.